# How to keep materials alpha colors set to 1 when stopping the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeInOut : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<Material> mats = new List<Material>();

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (Transform g in transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
        {
            if (g.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>() != null)
            {
                var l = g.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().sharedMaterials.ToList();
                foreach(Material mat in l)
                {
                    mats.Add(mat);
                }                
            }
        }  
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeToTogether(mats, 0, 0.5f));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FadeTo(List<Material> materials, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < materials.Count; i++)
        {
            Color color = materials[i].color;
            float startOpacity = color.a;

            float t = 0;

            while (t < duration)
            {
                t += Time.deltaTime;
                float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

                color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

                materials[i].color = color;

                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FadeToTogether(List<Material> materials, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {
        float t = 0;
        List<float> startOpacities = new List<float>();
        foreach (var material in materials)
        {
            startOpacities.Add(material.color.a);
        }

        while (t < duration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            for (int i = 0; i < materials.Count; i++)
            {
                Color color = materials[i].color;
                color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacities[i], targetOpacity, blend);
                materials[i].color = color;
            }
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

        if (targetOpacity == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeToTogether(mats, 1, 0.5f));
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeToTogether(mats, 0, 0.5f));
        }
    }
}
```

All the materials rendering mode are set to Fade.

The problem is when i stop the game the alpha color stay in the editor at the value when i stopped the game so the character/object with the materials sometimes is half faded out or sometimes faded out completely.

Is there a way to make that when i stop the game it will set the materials alpha color to 1?

I tried to add this to the bottom of the script but it's not doing anything :

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeToTogether(mats, 1, 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Time.scale = 0` to stop the game, you should know that `yield retun null`  does not take into account `Time.Scale`. So change to solve the problem as below:

```cs
while (true)
{
    Debug.Log("Ignores Time.scale...");
    yield return null;
}
```

---

---

```cs
while (true)
{
    Debug.Log("Considers Time.scale...");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because when you're changing materials - you don't change something inside GameObjects, you're changing game files.

Application.Quit() doesn't work in editor cos it's a function for compiled game, so if you build it - it will work.

What you can do is copy material's properties into renderer component

```
GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.CopyPropertiesFromMaterial(mat);
```

P.S. Didn't test it, so try it and send feedback

P.P.S Also tell me if I didn't understand your question correctly